# Jquery Stop event handlers being binded again when returning same page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

SongPage view i have following Jquery code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".foo", function () {
    changeSong();
});

 function changeSong() {
            $.ajax({
                url: path,
                method: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#body-wrapper').html(data);
                }
            });
 }
```

The changeSong function returns the SongPage view again, because of this it binds another `click` function again, I can use `.one()` to make sure it only executes each one once, but is there a way I can do this without creating a new click handler each time?

Comment: test if the data was appended and prevent any ajax call from that click event

Comment: Have you added this codes in your SongPage view?

Comment: Code is in my SongPage view yes. @madalinivascu
I am not appending though, I am replacing each time.

Comment: Why bind the event handler to `document`? If you're including the handler code in your SongPage HTML, then you know its structure, and can bind the handler to `#body-wrapper`. The old handler would be destroyed when it gets removed.

Comment: @Palpatim Never thought of that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, you can call .off() before calling .on(). But that does not seem very clean to me.

Cannot you just not put the script all over again in the page ? Like doing a non-ajax request for example ?

Comment: I shall try that first and see if I can. If not I shall use .Off(). thanks,